# Qt/VTK: No appropriate default constructor available (custom interactor)

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I have a GUI called MainWindow where I am rendering some things in the constructor.
Above this constructor I declared a custom class of the interactor to implement the function OnRightButtonDown(). 
In this function I want to call a function from my MainWindow class.

When I am running the code the error:

> "No appropriate default constructor available"

occurs which refers to this line:

```
vtkStandardNewMacro(customMouseInteractorStyle);
```

How can I change my code to enable a constructor with argument?

```
    class customMouseInteractorStyle : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
    {
    public:
        static customMouseInteractorStyle* New();
        vtkTypeMacro(customMouseInteractorStyle,   vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);
        MainWindow *mainWin;

        customMouseInteractorStyle(MainWindow *ptr) : mainWin(ptr)
        {

        }

        virtual void OnRightButtonDown()
        {
            mainWin->function();
            vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnRightButtonDown();
        }
    };
    vtkStandardNewMacro(customMouseInteractorStyle);

Test1::Test1(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
       //Rendering
       ....
       //

    vtkSmartPointer<customMouseInteractorStyle> style =   //My custom class!!!
    vtkSmartPointer<customMouseInteractorStyle>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(style);

    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();

}

void MainWindow::function()
{
}
```

Comment: Your constructor for customMouseInteractorStyle: `customMouseInteractorStyle(MainWindow *ptr)` needs to  be parameterless `customMouseInteractorStyle()` Use a separate function to set the pointer to MainWindow.

Comment: How is the initialisation done? 
This is not allowed:

 void  ptr_function(MainWindow *ptr) : mainWindow(ptr)
 {
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
 class customMouseInteractorStyle : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
    {
    public:
        static customMouseInteractorStyle* New();
        vtkTypeMacro(customMouseInteractorStyle,   vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);
        MainWindow *mainWin;

        customMouseInteractorStyle()
        {

        }

        void  function(MainWindow *ptr)
        {
           mainWin = ptr;
        }

        virtual void OnRightButtonDown()
        {
            mainWin->function();
            vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnRightButtonDown();
        }
    };
    vtkStandardNewMacro(customMouseInteractorStyle);

Test1::Test1(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
       //Rendering
       ....
       //

    vtkSmartPointer<customMouseInteractorStyle> style =   //My custom class!!!
    vtkSmartPointer<customMouseInteractorStyle>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(style);
    style->function(this);

    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();

}

void MainWindow::function()
{
}
```